# No reputation change signals if subtracted from bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, reputation, bounty

Right now I am observing the following.

Usually every time I get an upvote somewhere, I get a signal about it in the upper right corner. Recently I declared a bounty (and awarded it for an answer) at somebody else's question. Now when I get upvotes, no signal comes. When I go to my page, there the reputation increase is reflected in the way it affects the decrease caused by the bounty (it was -100, then became -85, then -75, etc.).

It is a minor issue, but still - is not it possible to continue receiving these signals regardless whether I had reputation decrease or any other circumstances?

Comment: Related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [New Rep indicator stops when having negative score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209021). Some of the comments there suggest that the counter is reset as soon as you click on the achievements/reputation indicator.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the information! Yes it seems I did something like that, now it started working again. This information could be put in an answer, but we do not know for sure what triggers it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე While I'm not 100% confident, I believe the "concept" is that SO doesn't like notifying users of *negative* rep changes. So if the sum total of the unread notifications is negative, you won't see the signal, but once you've read them, they cease to count towards the sum.